# Positive and negative powers of small parameter in perturbation problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, approximations

I'd like to perturbatively handle an eigenvalue problem similar to this:
$$
\lambda f = (\hat{H} + (1/\epsilon^2) \hat{V} + \epsilon {W}) f,
$$
where $f$ is a function, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, $\epsilon$ is a small parameter, and the rest are linear operators. The problem is, that if one writes a series for the eigenvalue and the eigenfunction,
$$
f = f_0 + \epsilon f_1 + \epsilon^2 f_2 + ...\\
\lambda = \lambda_0 + \epsilon \lambda_1 + \epsilon^2 \lambda_2 + ...,
$$
one will get e.g.
$$
\lambda_0 f_0 = \hat{H} f_0 + \hat{V} f_2\\
\lambda_1 f_0 + \lambda_0 f_1 = \hat{H} f_1 + \hat{W} f_0 + \hat{V} f_3\\
...
$$
i.e. the different orders of the series start to mix. Is there a way to develop a systematic perturbation theory for this case?

Answer (score 0):

A perturbation approach requires the additional perturbing Hamiltonian to be a weak disturbance to the unperturbed system. However in your statement you have the small parameter $\epsilon$ at the denominator. It is an inconsistency, that is the smaller the parameter the higher the disturbance! The system posted in the question is unstable.